# I can't install dependencies for React Native Projects correctly

Tags: react-native, npm, dependencies, expo, npm-install

So I tried running a React Native project in my android emulator using Expo, but every time I install someone else's project, I'm not able to run it.

This is how I install the project along with its dependencies:

```
> git clone https://github.com/nabendu82/NativeRestaurantSearc.git
> cd NativeRestaurantSearc
> npm install
> npm start
```

When I run all this, I recieve this error message:

```
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-18T10_46_25_411Z-debug.log
```

This is a complete log of the run:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Yassi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.6
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
6 info lifecycle @~start: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Yassi\Bureaublad\React Native\NativeRestaurantSearc\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Users\Yassi\Ap;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz;C:\Users\Yassi\Documents\stardog-7.0.1;C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: C:\Users\Yassi\Bureaublad\React Native\NativeRestaurantSearc
10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yassi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Yassi\Bureaublad\React Native\NativeRestaurantSearc
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Yassi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I think this has to do with npm not installing the dependencies correctly. There must be going something wrong when I do this, because this is the message I recieve when I run npm install:

```
added 809 packages from 438 contributors and audited 37723 packages in 119.347s
found 1072 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

What can I do to fix this? I tried reinstalling npm but that doesn't work.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59567631/9432559

Comment: remove `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and `cd ios` and remove `Pods/` and `Podfile.lock` and do `cd ..` and `npm i`

Comment: Your suggestion worked @SDushan !

Comment: @Y.Ben If that answer has solved your question please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't give the dependency's name the sample code is:

> git clone https://github.com/nabendu82/NativeRestaurantSearc.git
> cd NativeRestaurantSearc
> npm install (dependency's name)
> npm start