# Can't start any React Native Projects in Expo any more

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm flummoxed after 2 hours of trying to figure this out. Long story short, when I download a Native React Project like the [Native Base KitchenSink](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink) and run it, I get errors. Not just this project but on others.

All I did was:

1. Download the zip file and explode it
2. "yarn" and then "yarn start"

Then I get this error 
[image]

I get similar regex errors on totally different out-of-the-box projects as well. So I'm fairly certain it is something on my machine and not this 3rd party code.

Here is the error from a different project
[image]

I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall Node and expo-cli (via npm and yarn)

But I get the same error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't know what to uninstall at this point.
I get lots of warning messages when installing but no errors.

What do I reinstall at this point?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59567631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this occurs on old projects that use old versions of packages that aren't supported by new versions of node.js. [this issue was fixed in this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/metro/pull/468) and backported but perhaps not to a version old enough to be supported by the projects you are trying to run. you can revert back to an older version of node.js if you must run them - node.js v10.x would be a good choice.

if you're not too opinionated about the library choice, you may want to try a more actively maintained ui library like [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/) instead.

Comment: Thanks Man. Boy I spent a ton of time on this. That second error was the one I looked at the most and it doesn't indicate where the issue is at all.

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1074#issuecomment-546167583